# Select a row in bootstrap style table when the row is clicked

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

How to highlight a row from the table when it is clicked? I have tried using `onClick` function but I cannot achieve it.

This is the function I used for mapping the table data to td tag.

```
displayData() {   
       let x;
       if (this.props.data) {
       x = this.props.data.map(item => (
       <tr>
       <td> {item.height} </td>
       </tr>
      ));
    }
    return x;
    }
```

Here I have called this function inside the render function.

```
        <Table id="tableId" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th> height </th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
     <tbody> {this.displayData()} </tbody>
     </Table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide an `key` to every `td`, then a `className` property that will change depending on the id existing currently in the `state` and of course an `onClick` event handler that will fill in the state with the clicked id, therefore this block:

```
  if (this.props.data) {
   x = this.props.data.map((item,key) => (
   <tr>
   <td
     key={key}
     onClick={this.handleCellClick(key)}
     className={`${this.state.checkedId===key? 'highlighted-cell': ''}`}
      > {item.height} </td>
   </tr>
  ));
}
```

and your `handleCellClick` function can be implemented as follows:

```
handleCellClick = (key) => (event) => {

if(this.state.checkedId===key){
   this.setState({
      checkedId: '',
     });
   }else{
   this.setState({
      checkedId: key,
     });
   }
  }
```

finally your `highlited-cell` class can be written as per your preferences:

```
.highlighted-cell {
   background-color: blue;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will try it.

Comment: You're welcome, you may as well upvote and pick the answer as the right answer thank you